# Assets precompiling error with jQuery UI plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vps, precompiling

I've been wracking my brains over this problem for the last couple of hours.

I have an issue with running `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace`

due to the addition of jQuery UI into the mix.

```
// Libraries
//= require externalLibraries/d3/d3.v2
//= require externalLibraries/d3/d3.layout
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/externalLibraries/highcharts/highcharts
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
//
//= require reminder
//
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_directory .
```

Here is the trace:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Killed

  (in /home/RailsApplications/TwilioApplications/releases/20120918052259/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:142:in `exec_runtime'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/uglifier-1.3.0/lib/uglifier.rb:100:in `compile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `block in js_compressor='
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in `block in evaluate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `evaluate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:23:in `block in compile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/...]
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

The weirdest part is that when I run this command on my development environment, it totally works.

And on my production environment if I remove the jquery ui reference, it continues as normal, so definitely that is the problem.  Here is my Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  # gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
end

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'jasmine'
  gem 'jasminerice'
  gem 'guard-jasmine'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem "factory_girl_rails"  
  gem "factory_girl" 
  gem "capybara"  
  gem "webrat"
  gem "guard-rspec"  
  gem "spork", "> 0.9.0.rc" 
  gem "guard-spork"
end

# OAuth 
gem 'rack-oauth2'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'doorkeeper'

gem 'rack-pjax'
gem 'sunspot_rails'

gem 'rabl'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'd3_rails'
gem 'backbone-on-rails'


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'unicorn-rails'
gem 'redis'
gem 'redis-rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'redis-store', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'redis-objects', :require => 'redis/objects'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'resque', :require => 'resque/server'
gem 'thin'
gem 'localtunnel'
gem 'twilio-ruby'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.beta'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
gem 'debugger'

# To use in similarity calculations
gem 'amatch'
gem 'chronic'

# Monitoring
gem 'resque-pool'
gem 'god'

gem 'whenever'

# Etc. stuff
gem 'progress_bar'
```

Any ideas? (let me know if I'm missing something critical as I'm currently extremely tired)

Thanks

Comment: Does it make a difference if you run rake assets:clean locally before precompiling?

Comment: Unrelated comment: you should avoid using the old aws-s3 gem with the the newer aws-sdk gem.  They are not namespace compatible.  Paperclip used to rely on aws-s3. It now relies on aws-sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Remove from your Gemfile:

```
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

And change **//= require jquery.ui.all** in your application.js to **//= require jquery-ui**

Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post while trying to solve the same problem, so I thought I share my solution.

The [jquery-rails gem](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) already comes with jQuery UI and it will conflict with [jquery-ui-rails gem](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) when you try to enable this way, so you have to choose which JQuery UI to use. Checkout the [**jquery-rails page**](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) and look under **Rails 3.1 and greater**.

Here's what I did:

(1) Enable jquery-ui in application.js

```
//= jquery-ui
```

(2) Get the default theme from jquery-ui-rails gem

(2-1) In gem file add `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'`

(2-2) In application.css add `*= jquery.ui.all`

You could also develop your own theme from themeroller and use it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'
```

remove `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'`

`//= require jquery-ui` in app.js

fixed this for me